# Converting month name to month number using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a a better solution than what I have below to convert a month name to a month number using JavaScript or PHP?

I did like this:

```
$monNum =  date('n',strtotime($staff->curMonth));
```

Comment: I tried using switch case but i thinks its not good idea...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could keep an object of key/value pairs where the key is the month name and the value is the month number:

```
var months = {
    January: 1,
    February: 2,
    ...
};
```

and then:

```
var monthNumber = months['April'];
```

or:

```
var monthNumber = months.April;
```

Comment: This is really the only sensibly way of doing it, short of a hideous switch statement or if block.