# How compare two dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a two date like from and to date.
date format like **28-Sep-2013** and **01-Sep-2013**.
I want to compare date and show error message.
I have use this code,

```
     var from = $('#<%= txtFDateEdu.ClientID %>').val();
     var to = $('#<%= txtTDateEdu.ClientID %>').val();

     var dateTypeVar = $('#<%= txtFDateEdu.ClientID %>').datepicker('getDate');
     var dateTypeVarto = $('#<%= txtFDateEdu.ClientID %>').datepicker('getDate');
     $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', dateTypeVar);

     var datefrom = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yyyy', dateTypeVar);
     var dateto = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yyyy', dateTypeVarto);
         alert(datefrom);    

         if (datefrom > dateto) {
             alert("Success");
          }
         else {

         }
```

This code is not working properly. Some issue occur in date format. Please any one help me to solve date format issue and compare  date properly.
i also use this code.

```
var from = $('#<%= txtFDateEdu.ClientID %>').val();
                var to = $('#<%= txtTDateEdu.ClientID %>').val(;)

                alert(from);
                alert(to);
                var datefrom = new Date(from);
                var dateto = new Date(to);
                alert(datefrom);
                 alert(dateto);
                if (datefrom > dateto) {
                    alwer("Success");
                }
                else {

                }
```

but this also not work properly.

Comment: _" this code is not working properly.some issue occur in date format"_ can you please be a bit(read: lot) more descriptive on what's the problem.

Comment: yes, issue in date format.i have a date format like 28-Sep-2013.i want to convert date than compare.

Comment: @jitendrakumar: if you know the cause, you should be able to fix it. Try harder.

Comment: `datepicker.formatDate` returns a string. You can't compare two strings as `datefrom > dateto` and expect Javascript to know they're supposed to be dates. Convert them to the correct `Date` object

Comment: Can you provide the error output?

Comment: Use datejs to convert the dates

Comment: @RGraham:how to convert 28-Sep-2013 to 28/09/2013.

Comment: @jitendrakumar Why would you want to? `dateTypeVar` [is a date](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate)

Comment: I only want compare from and to date.and date format is 28-sept-2013.

Comment: @jitendrakumar forget about the date format - those are _presentation_ issues.  `Date` objects are directly comparable.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting a given date to a string, just skip this step:

```
 var datefrom = $('#<%= txtFDateEdu.ClientID %>').datepicker('getDate');
 var dateto = $('#<%= txtFDateEdu.ClientID %>').datepicker('getDate');

     if (datefrom > dateto) {
         alert("Success");
      }
     else {

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the two `Date` objects *before* you've converted them to strings:

```
var dateTypeVar = $('#<%= txtFDateEdu.ClientID %>').datepicker('getDate');
var dateTypeVarto = $('#<%= txtFDateEdu.ClientID %>').datepicker('getDate');

if (dateTypeVar > dateTypeVarto) {
    ...
}
```

The comparison operator will automatically take the value of the two date objects via `.valueOf()`, that being the milliseconds elapsed since 1970/01/01 00:00:00.

Answer (score -1):

I also use date picker, normally i use following script.

```
   function compare_dates(valid_to, valid_from){
  var splited_to = valid_to.split("-")
  var to_date_monthfield=splited_to[1];
  var to_date_dayfield=splited_to[0];
  var to_date_yearfield=splited_to[2];
  var to_date = new Date(to_date_yearfield, to_date_monthfield-1, to_date_dayfield);

  var splited_from = valid_from.split("-");
  var from_date_monthfield=splited_from[1];
  var from_date_dayfield=splited_from[0];
  var from_date_yearfield=splited_from[2];
  var from_date = new Date(from_date_yearfield, from_date_monthfield-1, from_date_dayfield);

  var cur_date = new Date();
  if(!(from_date > cur_date.setDate(cur_date.getDate() - 1))){
    return false;
  }
  if(!(to_date > from_date)){
    return false;
  }
  return true;

}
```

This expects your date date to be in **dd//mm/yyyy** format

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date-using-javascript) i found something use full. You can use it with my code.

```
new Date(Date.parse(month_string +" 1, 2012")).getMonth()+1
```

you can replace **monthfield** with above code. or you also can use a [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181538/converting-month-name-to-month-number-using-javascript) way.

Comment: Not that this is *wrong* as such, but it's a little naive and verbose too. It performs `split` multiple times on the same object/parameters and does no error checking. Also why not just return `to_date.compare(from_date)` and let the caller decide the comparison rather than hardcoding it inside the function

Comment: i have date format like 28-Sep-2013.please provide me solution regarding this format.

Comment: I have changed my answer bit and added couple of links. Please check that out.