# Replacing month name with number

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far i have changed the date format from "24 Feb 2014" to "Feb-24-2014" using:

```
    var dateStart = date;
    var arr = dateStart.split(' ');
    console.log(arr[1]+"-"+arr[0]+"-"+arr[2]);
```

How would I extract the month from arr[1] and replace its equivalent numerical value?

(WHAT i'VE TRIED: I've created an array and an each function to loop through this array and return the month names values (i.e, 2 from Feb, 5 from May)).

ANSWER: The bit that I was looking for specifically in my case was creating the split "arr[1]" as an indexer for the dateArray:

```
dateArray[arr[1]]
```

Comment: create a array of months and do lookup

Comment: If you're trying to get the month from a string then just use `new Data(dateString).getMonth() + 1;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to convert month name to month number in JS ? (Jan = 01)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566552/easiest-way-to-convert-month-name-to-month-number-in-js-jan-01)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566552/easiest-way-to-convert-month-name-to-month-number-in-js-jan-01

Comment: Are the month strings going to be in the current locale's language, or a fixed language?  If you can't guarantee that the current locale is the same as used by the month strings then beware of any solution using a `Date` object!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a hash - like that you don't have to iterate over an array.

```
 var dateHash = {
    Jan : 1,
    Feb: 2,
    Mar: 3,
    Apr: 4,
    May: 5,
    Jun: 6,
    Jul: 7,
    Aug: 8,
    Sep: 9,
    Oct: 10,
    Nov: 11,
    Dec: 12
   };

var newDate = dateHash[arr[1]]+"-"+arr[0]+"-"+arr[2];
```

Comment: Just a quick note, if you need the trailing zeros, you'll have to make the numbers strings: Jan: '01', Feb: '02', etc

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
var i;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    alert(new Date(Date.parse(arr[i] +" 1, 2012")).getMonth()+1);
}
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z8WZG/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could keep an object of key/value pairs where the key is the month name and the value is the month number:

```
var months = {
    January: 1,
    February: 2,
    ...
};
```

and then:

```
var monthNumber = months['April'];
```

or:

Reference [Converting month name to month number using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181538/converting-month-name-to-month-number-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun I did this:

```
function getMonthFromString(mon){
   return new Date(Date.parse(mon +" 1, 2012")).getMonth()+1
}
```

Bonus: it also supports full month names :-D Or the new improved version that simply returns -1 - change it to throw the exception if you want (instead of returning -1):

```
function getMonthFromString(mon){

   var d = Date.parse(mon + "1, 2012");
   if(!isNaN(d)){
      return new Date(d).getMonth() + 1;
   }
   return -1;
 }
```

Source : [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566552/easiest-way-to-convert-month-name-to-month-number-in-js-jan-01)

Answer (score 0):

**To transform month into number:**

```js
var dateString = "24 Feb 2014";
var date = new Date(dateString)
var result = date.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + date.getDate() + "-" + date.getFullYear()
console.log(result)
```

**To transform number into month:**

```js
var dateString = "24-2014";
var monthNumber = 2;
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
var result = months[monthNumber - 1] + "-" + dateString
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var month=new Array(12);
        month[0]="Jan";
        month[1]="Feb";
        month[2]="Mar";
        month[3]="Apr";
        month[4]="May";
        month[5]="Jun";
        month[6]="Jul";
        month[7]="Aug";
        month[8]="Sep";
        month[9]="Oct";
        month[10]="Nov";
        month[11]="Dec";

month[mm] === value!!
```

Comment: 1. this doesn't solve the problem, 2. it's a horrible way of creating an array!

Comment: @Alnitak - Please explain as why its horrible way?

Comment: The normal way would be `var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', ...]`